# After collapse delimiter - Inline citation options in mendeley visual CSL editor?

Tags: citations, mendeley, csl

I would like to add some specific after-collapse-delimiters in the mendeley visual CSL editor.

In the "Advanced" - "Global Formatting Options" under "Inline Citations" i enabled "Year-suffix-delimiter", "after-collapse-delimiter" and "cite-group-delimiter".
[image: delimiter options]

This leaves me with the following inline citations:

**(Falco 1970, 1991, Manate 1976, 2003)**

**(Franto 1990; Franto et al. 1994, 2016, Franto and Ranga 2006, 2009, 2012a, b, 2014)**

**(Falco 1970, 1991, Manate 1976, 2003; Franto 1990)**

However, what I don't quite get is that the delimiter changes between **;** and **,**.

I would like to have it formatted like the following:

**(Falco 1970, 1991; Manate 1976, 2003)**

**(Franto 1990; Franto et al. 1994, 2016; Franto and Ranga 2006, 2009, 2012a, b, 2014)**

**(Falco 1970, 1991; Manate 1976, 2003; Franto 1990)**

Any suggestions on how I could achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little hard to say without the whole style, but a couple of things to note:

1. Since the `cite-group-delimiter` defaults to ", " anyway and you don't actually need a different delimiter after collapse then regularly between citations (see (Franto 1990; example), so don't need `after-collapse-delimiter` at all, all you need to set is `delimiter="; "` under "Inline Citation" > Layout and you'll get exactly the behavior you want. See e.g. the APA style.
2. Finally, especially if you're using the editor on Mendeley, I don't think they update the processor frequently (compare to editor.citationstyles.org which was updated about a month ago) so it's possible you're experiencing a bug with the citation processor that has since been fixed.